# Calculating the power of an experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, experiment-design, statistical-power

I'm working through a question in Gelman - Regression and Other Stories and I find myself getting confused with the following question;

'Power, type M error, and type S error: Consider the experiment shown in Figure 16.1 where the true effect could not realistically be more than 2 percentage points and it is estimated with a standard error of 8.1 percentage points.

(a) Assuming the estimate is unbiased and normally distributed and the true effect size is 2 percentage points, use simulation to answer the following questions: What is the power of this study? If only “statistically significant” results are reported, what is the average type M error and what is the type S error rate?'

[image]

I understand the question says to use simulation but I would like to understand it analytically first. My calculation is as follows:

I choose n = 1000 somewhat arbitrarily as the questions advises using simulation

Declare statistical significance with values +- 2 SDs from 0. Therefore the probability of a T2 error given mu = 2 = Pr( X <= 16.2 | mu is 2)  = Pr(Z < 16.2-2/SE) = Pr(Z < 55), which, using R;

```
 B = pnorm(55,0,1)
```

is approximately 1 ---> Power = 1-B approx 0.

Is the power of this experiment really 0%?

Comment: Where does 16.2 analytically even come from?

Comment: 0 + 2SD. In that expression, it is the probability of getting a value from a distribution with mean 0 that is less than 2SDs, i.e., not leading to a rejection of the null. So the probability of getting a non-significant value, when the null should be rejected because mu = 2 and not 0, is the probability of getting a value less than 2SDs giving the distribution has mean 2.  Does that make sense... ?

Comment: So the *true* mean is 2, the sample mean is observed to be 16.2 with SE of 8.1 which is statistically significant at the two-sided 0.05 level. You then ask: what's the power of the analysis? If the null is mu=0, but assume the true mean is 2 and SE = 8.1 then the 2-sided power is actually `pnorm(1.96*8.1, 2, 8.1, FALSE) + pnorm(-1.96*8.1, 2, 8.1, TRUE) ` which is actually <6%. The problem is the original result 16.2 was highly improbable even with mu=2. If you assume the true mean is 16.2, you just regurgitate the p-value.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks for your help!